# sudo: ./install.sh: command not found is not working on Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, simple-openni

I've been following this tutorial in order to get SimpleOpenNI installed on my mac but I keep getting stuck at installing the OpenNI and NITE components because it requires me to navigate to the folders in Terminal and then run "sudo ./install.sh". I do this and I get this error:

sudo: ./install.sh: command not found

I've installed Command Line Tools in Xcode and everything.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry here is the link to the tutorial: http://creativec0d1ng.blogspot.ca/2012/08/installing-openni-on-osx-lionmountain.html

Comment: Which step fails? I see two with `sudo ./install.sh`.

Comment: The very first step with that command in it. But really running that command for any of the steps comes up with the same error.

Comment: right before you do the "`sudo`" thing, type in "`ls`" in Terminal. That prints out a list of files. Do you see "`install.sh`" in that list of files? If not, type in "`pwd`" and tell us where you are.

Comment: If you do as above and there is an install.sh, do `ls -l` and check that it is actually executable (`-rwxr-xr-x`)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was making a really dumb typo error - must've just been tired. All good now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 32):

The reason why that happens is because the script you are trying to execute needs the right permissions.

Type:

```
sudo chmod a+x install.sh
```

and then try again.

Comment: I was having trouble installing rapid7's InsightAgent on an AWS instance via PuTTY, and this line of code fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

> In directory of install.sh

```
prompt$ sh install.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

first open Terminal, type cd and than drag the map into Terminal and press enter. Now type sudo ./install.sh and it will work. Took me very long to find out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

.sh scripts should have "\n" line breaks.
"Command not found" also occurs if "\r\n" line breaks are used.
Well at least this is the case on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` as root, `not autorun.sh`

Once you've inserted the Guest Additions ISO, open Files and open the disc from the sidebar. Then, right-click in the background of the window where autorun.sh is and select

> Open in > Terminal

Now you can run the following command to install the Guest Additions:

> sudo ./VboxLinuxAdditions.run

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie but here is an answer that may help with the sh problem...I am running Armbian on an orange pi prime H5 SBC and I had downloaded and unzipped arduino ide well after 2 hours of searching and trying I hit it ....open the directory where the file you want to open or install is ...now at the top of the directory open a terminal(under file it will say open a terminal here).now the sh filename.sh will work.